# Unable to reference an AWS API Gateway Usage Plan as a data source in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, hcl

I have two Terraform projects that are deployed at different times. One of them needs to reference an API Gateway Usage plan in the other project, which should be deployed first. The code looks like this:

```cs
data "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "usage_plan" {
  name = "name-of-usage-plan"
}
```

However, when I execute `terraform plan`, I get the following:

```
data "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "usage_plan" {

The provider hashicorp/aws does not support data source "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan".

Did you intend to use the managed resource type "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan"? If so, declare this using a "resource" block instead of a "data" block.
```

I think that if I use a "resource" block it will just create a new usage plan, which I don't want to do.

I'm using terraform 1.1.0 with the aws provider v4.6.0.

What other options do I have? Can I use the AWS CLI to get a reference to the resource? I only need to get its ARN to add it to an IAM statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no data source called `aws_api_gateway_usage_plan`. TF does not support that. Please check [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_usage_plan.html) for list of existing data sources.

You have to implement your own [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) to query API stage details.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I created a script that provides a JSON to `stdout` and Terraform parses that.